# iText is not rendering image in Grails web application

Tags: grails, pdf, itext

We are trying to send an image as a stream to a method in Grails 2.4.3.

```
def imgStream
imgStream = servletContext.classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/assets/Logo.jpg")
```

We call in another service to render the PDF

```
ByteArrayOutputStream  output = licensePlanReportsService.renderLicensingPlanPDF(licensingPlanInstance, internal, imgStream)
```

We are using com.lowagie.text.Image from iText 2.1.7 and poi 3.9-20121203

```
if(imgStream) {
    Image logo = Image.getInstance(imgStream.getBytes())
    logo.scaleAbsolute(128.64, 88.32)
    logo.setAbsolutePosition(25, 485)
    document.add(logo)
}
```

The image is not rendering for us on our output the PDF report.  Does this seem to be the correct way to render the image to the PDF?

Comment: iText 2.1.7 = not a chance at getting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by changing the initial call by using the following code:

```
imgStream = grailsAttributes.getApplicationContext().getResource("Logo.jpg").getInputStream()
```

Instead of the initial way

```
imgStream = servletContext.classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/assets/Logo.jpg")
```

Thanks,

Tom